# How do I cite and translate poetry in MLA format?

Tags: mla, formatting

I hope to translate poems from other languages to English, but I don't know how I    am supposed to cite the original author and include myself as the translator in MLA format.

I will translate from webpages, books, magazines, and other formats if there are any interesting poems.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. What does your research show?

Comment: Questions about citations are [on-topic on Writers.SE](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1969/are-questions-about-mla-formatting-on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Poems are handled the same way as books.

There are quite a few online citation generators that may be of help. [owl.purdue.edu](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/research_and_citation/mla_style/mla_formatting_and_style_guide/mla_works_cited_page_books.html) has good alternatives for whether you'd like to emphasize the original author or the translator.

Usually, you cite the original author:

> Foucault, Michel. *Madness and Civilization: A History of Insanity in the Age of Reason.* Translated by Richard Howard, Vintage-Random House, 1988.

Rarely, you emphasize the translator:

> Howard, Richard, translator. *Madness and Civilization: A History of Insanity in the Age of Reason.* By Michel Foucault, Vintage-Random House, 1988.